# What is versionCodeMajor? And what is the difference with versionCode?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I just found that [`PackageInfo.versionCode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionCode) is deprecated in Android Pie. They point you to use [`PackageInfo.getLongVersionCode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#getLongVersionCode()) instead. The JavaDoc of this new method is:

> Return [`versionCode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#AndroidManifest_versionCode) and [`versionCodeMajor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#AndroidManifest_versionCodeMajor) combined together as a single long value. The [`versionCodeMajor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#AndroidManifest_versionCodeMajor) is placed in the upper 32 bits.

But what is `versionCodeMajor`? How must I use it? What's the difference between `versionCodeMajor` and the old `versionCode`?

The documentation of it say nearlly nothing:

> Internal major version code. This is essentially additional high bits for the base version code; it has no other meaning than that higher numbers are more recent. This is not a version number generally shown to the user, that is usually supplied with R.attr.versionName.

Comment: I thought it was pretty self-explanatory. They've expanded the version code from an `int` to a `long`. The way to do that, in a backwards-compatible fashion, is to pack two `int`s into that `long`, where the low `int` is the old version code and the high `int` defaults to zero. I don't expect most people to need any of this, but clearly some product team at Google was unwise in their versioning practices and is running out of numbers.

Comment: Maybe they learned from the old mis-optimism that 640 KB will be "plenty" of RAM and decided to play it safe and not assume that 4 billion versions will always be enough. :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Up to now, the only way I've found to set `versionCodeMajor` with Android Studio 3.2.1 is through `AndroidManifest.xml` and disabling *InstantRun*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionCodeMajor="8" [...]
```

'cause setting it in `build.gradle` file you get

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxx.myapplicationp"
        minSdkVersion 'P'
        targetSdkVersion 'P'
        versionCode 127
        //versionCodeMajor 8
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

> Could not find method versionCodeMajor() for arguments

So, having set your chosen major version code number in `AndroidManifest.xml` and having disable *InstantRun* then you could get it in this way:

```
static long getAppVersionCode(Context context) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        PackageInfo pinfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        long returnValue = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        //if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P
                && !"P".equals(Build.VERSION.CODENAME) /* This 'cause the dev preview */) {
            returnValue = pinfo.versionCode;
        } else {
            returnValue = pinfo.getLongVersionCode();
            Log.d("AAA", "Full long value: " + returnValue);
            Log.d("AAA", "Major Version Code (your chosen one) " + (returnValue >> 32)); // 8 in this scenario
            Log.d("AAA", "Version Code (your chosen one) " + (int)(returnValue & 0x00000000ffffffff)); // 127 in this scenario
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

or you could use [PackageInfoCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/pm/PackageInfoCompat) like that:

```
static long getAppVersionCode(Context context) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        PackageInfo pinfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        long returnValue = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        returnValue = PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(pinfo);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            int majorCode = (int)(returnValue >> 32);
            int versionCode = (int)(returnValue & 0x00000000ffffffff); // or simply returnValue

            Log.d("AAA", "Full long value: " + returnValue);
            Log.d("AAA", "Major Version Code (your chosen one) " + majorCode); // 8 in this scenario
            Log.d("AAA", "Version Code (your chosen one) " + versionCode); // 127 in this scenario
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

And this should answer how to use it or a way to.

For when and why using it... I guess it's up to you... as, as you pointed out, the documentation tells you nothing on why you should use it. What doc says it’s you should present to your users only the well known versionNumber.

I guess they add some more bits to versionCode ‘cause they needed a greater number for their versioning ^^’

That said, if you dind’t set the `versionCodeMajor` either in `AndroidManifest.xml` or in the `build.gradle` file (when it will handle it) or you set it to `0` then this value is identical to the old `versionNumber` deprecated field.

Comment: @DanielWilson my answer or what android did? ^^’

Comment: What Android did :)

Answer (score -1):

Another way to get version name and version code is by BuildConfig

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
```