# Android SDK 28 - versionCode in PackageInfo has been deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie, package-info

I just upgraded my app's `compileSdkVersion` to `28` (Pie).

I'm getting a compilation warning:

> warning: [deprecation] versionCode in PackageInfo has been deprecated

The warning is coming from this code:

```
final PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
int versionCode = info.versionCode;
```

I looked at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/pm/PackageInfo#versioncode), but it doesn't say anything about how to resolve this issue or what should be used instead of the deprecated field.

Comment: See also [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630237/what-is-versioncodemajor-and-what-is-the-difference-with-versioncode/53007631#53007631)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It says what to do [on the Java doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo#versionCode) (I recommend not using the Kotlin documentation for much; it's not really maintained well):

> versionCode
>
> This field was deprecated in API level 28. Use getLongVersionCode() instead, which includes both this and the additional versionCodeMajor attribute. The version number of this package, as specified by the  tag's versionCode attribute.

This is an API 28 method, though, so consider using [PackageInfoCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/pm/PackageInfoCompat). It has one static method:

```
getLongVersionCode(PackageInfo info)
```

Comment: See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630237/what-is-versioncodemajor-and-what-is-the-difference-with-versioncode/53007631#53007631)

Answer (score 54):

My recommended solution:

Include this in your main build.gradle :

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

then just use this code:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
long longVersionCode= PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(pInfo);
int versionCode = (int) longVersionCode; // avoid huge version numbers and you will be ok
```

In case you have problems adding appcompat library then just use this **alternative solution**:

```
final PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
int versionCode;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    versionCode = (int) pInfo.getLongVersionCode(); // avoid huge version numbers and you will be ok
} else {
    //noinspection deprecation
    versionCode = pInfo.versionCode;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth does Google have to turn the most banal thing into a science on its own?

Comment: Perfect Thank you for this solution, @Chuck you are correct .. rocket science for an int ...

Answer (score 11):

Just for others using Xamarin, my answer was:

```
public long GetBuild()
{
    var context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;
    PackageManager manager = context.PackageManager;
    PackageInfo info = manager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0);

    return info.LongVersionCode;
}
```

Comment: Note you can also support older SDKs by wrapping this code with a check of the SDK version: `if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.P)`

Comment: it's an Int not a long!!

Comment: no it's not @user1034912 .  It's even in the variable name 'longVersionCode' rather than the older 'versioncode'.  That's actually the whole point of this issue, it used to be int, then changed to long.

Answer (score 6):

Here the solution in **`kotlin`**:

```
val versionCode: Long =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.P) {
           packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).longVersionCode
    } else {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).versionCode.toLong()
    }
```

Comment: this is wrong. the longVersionCode has this if else inside.

Comment: @PedroRomão It's not wrong. `longVersionCode` is API level 28+ only.

Answer (score 4):

In **Kotlin** simple code to get versionCode in PackageInfo

```
val packageInfo = this.packageManager.getPackageInfo(this.packageName, 0)
val verCode = PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(packageInfo).toInt()
```

Answer (score 1):

As of API `33`, from a library:

```kotlin
<applicationContext>.run {
    val info =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) 
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
        else packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName,
            PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags.of(0))
    PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(info)
}
```

From your own app, this is still a valid answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21119027/2115403

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this extension variable:

```
val PackageInfo.versionCodeCompat: Long
    get() = PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(this)
```